# I want to add an arrow at the end of the line

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I tried this code

```html
<svg>
<g id="vc">
<defs>
    <marker id="arrowhead_bc" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" 
    refX="0" refY="3.5">
      <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <rect x='.5' y='0' width='120' height='.5' style="fill:red;stroke:red" marker-end="url(arrowhead_bc)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I want to add an arrow at the end of the line with angle position so that I can use a rect element?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to draw a line - use a line element.
- You're missing a # character in your url

```html
<svg>
<g id="vc">
<defs>
    <marker id="arrowhead_bc" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" 
    refX="0" refY="3.5">
      <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1='0.5' y1='3.5' x2='120' y2='3.5' style="fill:red;stroke:red" marker-end="url(#arrowhead_bc)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```